# Is dihedral group defined as following commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, dihedral-groups

> Let $G$ be the dihedral group defined as the set of all formal symbols $x^iy^j$, $i=0,1$, $j=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, where $x^2=e$, $y^n=e$, $xy=y^{-1}x$.

EDIT - My proof is wrong .But i will be thankful to someone who help's me to identify where i was wrong in my proof (due to which i will learn more).

The following is my proof -

since $xy = y^{-1}x$

$yx=xy^{-1}$

$x^ay^b.x^iy^j$ = $(x^ay^{b-1}y)(xx^{i-1}y^j)$

=$(x^ay^{b-1}xy^{-1})(x^{i-1}y^j)$

=$(x^{a+1}y^{-b})(x^{i-1}y^j)$

=$(x^{a+1}y^{-b+1}y^{-1}x)({x^{i-2}y^j})$

=$(x^{a+1}y^{-b+1}xy)({x^{i-2}y^j})$

=$(x^{a+2}y^{b})(x^{i-2}y^j)$

Repeating the process $i$ times we will get final answer as -

$x^{a+i}y^{b+j}$

from above proof we can also conclude that centre of the given group $G$ is $G$ itself.

Can someone tell at which how i am wrong ?

Comment: You have assumed $i$ to be even.  What if $i$ is odd, say $i=1$?  What does your third line from $x^ay^b. x^iy^j=\dots$ say?

Comment: Something must have gone wrong as in $D_4$ (or $D_8$ depending on how you name it), the symmetry group of the square, the centre is $\{1,y^2\}$.

Comment: @user10354138 $x^0$ which is identity element.No i don't think that even or odd $i$  is problem.

Comment: @RichardMartin  I will be very thankful to you if you tell me where i am wrong .

Comment: @user10354138 can you tell me where i am wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{True Concept:}$

If $n=1$ or $n=2$, then $D_{2n}$ is abelian and hence $\Bbb Z(D_{2n})=D_{2n}$. Suppose $n\geq 3$. By definition, we have $D_{2n}=\{a^ib^j: i=0,1, j=0,1,\cdots, n-1\}$ where $a$ is an element of order $2$, $b$ is an element of order $n$ and $a,b$ are related by the relation $ba=ab^{-1}$. It then follows that $b^2 a= bab^{-1}=ab^{-2}$ and in general
$$b^ra=ab^{-r}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$ for all integers $r \geq 0$. Now, since $a$ and $b$ together generate $D_{2n}$, an element of $D_{2n}$ is in the center if and only if it commutes with both $a$ and $b$. So $x=a^ib^j \in Z(D_{2n})$ if and only if $xa=ax$ and $xb=bx$. The condition $xb=bx$ gives us $a^ib^{j+1}=ba^ib^j$ and thus
$$a^ib=ba^i. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
Clearly we can have $i=0$ in $(2)$ but can we have $i=1$ ? The answer is no because if $i=1$, then $(2)$ gives $ab=ba$ and we know from $(1)$ that $ba=ab^{-1}$. But then $ab=ab^{-1}$ and so $b^2=1$, which is not possible because $n \geq 3$. So $i=0$ and thus $x=b^j$. The condition $xa=ax$ then becomes $b^ja=ab^j$ and hence, by $(1)$, $ab^{-j}=ab^j$. Therefore
$$b^{2j}=1. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$

Hence, since $o(b)=n$, we get from $(3)$ that $n \mid 2j$. Thus either $j=0$ or $2j=n$ because $0 \leq j \leq n-1$. If $j=0$, then $x=b^j=1$. If $2j=n$, then $n$ is even and $x=b^j = b^{n/2}$. So we have proved

$$
Z(D_{2n})=
\begin{cases} 
      D_{2n} &  \text{if} \ \ n=1,2  \\
      \{1\} & \text{if} \ \ n>2 \ \text{is odd} \\
      \{1,b^{\frac{n}{2}} & \text{if} \ \ n>2 \ \text{is even}
      \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Well i understood your answer but if you tell me where i am wrong then i will be more thankful to you